# Touch contact with circle sprite oversize

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've got a simple spritekit project in which I'm noticing that the point at which contact is registered with my sprite is occurring well outside the circle physics body.

Demonstrated here:

https://gfycat.com/DentalBriskAfricangroundhornbill

With showPhysics on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASSbL.png

Code for the object spawning the circles:

```
    func spawnObject() {
    object = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Oval")
    //object.fillColor = SKColor.white
    object.name = "ball"
    object.position = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 520)
    object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: object.size.width / 2)
    object.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    object.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = object.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask
    object.physicsBody?.friction = 0.2
    object.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
    object.physicsBody?.mass = 5
    addChild(object)
}
```

The circles themselves interact perfectly with one another - it appears touch is the outlier.

Would appreciate any assistance :)

Edit:
Example touch code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let tappedNodes = nodes(at: location)

            for node in tappedNodes {
                if node.name == "ball" {
                    node.alpha = 0.5
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Turn physics visual representation in your view controller and see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I added a screenshot showing how it looks with showPhysics on (its basically the same - it still doesn't show what is being clicked.)

Comment: Then it is likely related to how you handle touches.

Comment: I utilised what seemed to be quite basic which code I'd seen in various tutorials - I've edited in above.

Comment: You can use bodyAtPoint or bodiesAtPoint methods from SKPhysicsWorld. Other solutions would not be trivial. Also, I can't remember if this is how SKShapeNode works, but even if it behaves differently than SKSpriteNode, it is unperformant so I guess that is not an option for you (I see you have many objects on the scene).

Comment: Thanks for the help Whirlwind :) Will look into it